# Office.js APIs challenge with hosting App manifest, html, JS and Word files on sharepoint for Office

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365api, office-js

I have developed a variant of "Word-Add-in-Load-and-write-Open-XML" (example from GitHub).

My altered code is designed to load Word document sections into a Template Word document - allowing for different sequences and differing selections.

I am running on XAMPP - Apache with manifest trusted etc. is working fine on my local Word 2016 install, but I cannot find a way to transfer to SharePoint 2013.
The manifest file doesn't load when served from SharePoint.
I loaded the CSS and JS files according to all the guidance.

The HTML file when loaded as an add in Word -> Insert - Add in "my add-in" loads in a frame which fails, I have tried every trick but am clean out of ideas!
I do not have back end admin access to the SharePoint site, only SharePoint designer 2013 and scripting etc. enabled.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

@Jerry, to publish a addins for Office to SharePoint, you need to set up an add-in catalog to store the manifest.

> An add-in catalog is a dedicated site collection in a SharePoint web
>   application or SharePoint Online tenancy that hosts document libraries
>   for SharePoint Add-ins and Office Add-ins.

For details, you can refer the documents as following.

[Set up an add-in catalog on Office 365](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/set-up-an-add-in-catalog-on-office-365)

[Set up an add-in catalog on SharePoint](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/set-up-an-add-in-catalog-on-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, sadly the "add-in" catalogue on SharePoint requires admin access to the SharePoint environment, as this is a large corporate install I don't have that level of access. I'll reach out to our admin team and see if / how I can make a case. But if anyone knows how to serve non framed pages from SharePoint - I think this can be made to work without disrupting the whole SharePoint estate.